# Prove that $x-1$ divides $x^n-1$

Tags: polynomials

In algebra & polynomials, how do we prove that
$$x-1 \mid x^n -1?$$

Comment: FACTOR THEOREM, FACTOR THEOREM, FACTOR THEOREM.

Comment: both have $x=1$ as zero ...'

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Consider $(x-1)(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{n-1})$.

Comment: How do you derive $x^n-1 = (x-1)(1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1})$?

Comment: @Duane You can use long division to find the quotient of $x^n - 1$ by $x-1$.

Answer (score 11):

You can prove it by induction. $$x^{n+1}-1 = x^{n+1}-x^n + x^n -1 = (x-1)x^n + x^n-1$$

Answer (score 11):

Clearly $x\equiv 1 \pmod{x-1}$. Hence $x^n-1\equiv 1^n-1\equiv 0 \pmod{x-1}$, i.e. $x-1\mid x^n-1$.

Comment: This is beautiful!

Answer (score 8):

Hints: For any two  reals $\,a,b\,$ :

$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$$

Answer (score 5):

***Factorization method***

Clearly, $x^{n} - 1 = (x - 1)(x^{n - 1} + x^{n - 2} + \dots + 1)$.  Thus, $(x - 1) | (x^{n} - 1)$ since there exists the polynomial namely $(x^{n - 1} + x^{n - 2} + \dots + 1)$ that is multiplied by $(x - 1)$ to obtain $(x^{n} - 1)$.

***Substitution method***

Suppose that $x - 1 = 0 \rightarrow x = 1$.  If we substitute that value for $(x^{n} - 1)$, then clearly $1^{n} - 1 = 0$.  This shows that $(x^{n} - 1)$ has a factor $(x - 1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Apply division algorithm, what can be the remainder?

Answer (score 2):

By Remainder theorem $ f(x) = x^n -1 ,$  if $ f(1) = 0$, then $ (x-1)$ is a factor of $f(x) $ .

Answer (score 1):

Another proof by induction:
$$
x^{n+1}-x+x-1=x(x^{n}-1)+x-1
$$
RHS also divides $x-1$ because $x^n-1$ divides it by the assumption of the $n^{th}$ step

Comment: Please use "divide" the other way round. For example $x-1$ divides $x^n-1$ but $x^n-1$ does not divide $x-1$ in general.

Answer (score 0):

$x-1$ has as many zeros as its degree allows (i.e. one, and it's 1), and $x^n-1$ shares all those zeros. From that it follows that $x-1|x^n-1$, at least of you're working over a field. Over a ring (i.e. where you cannot, in general, divide) you also need that the coefficient of the largest power in $x-1$ divides the coefficient of the largest power in $x^n-1$, but you have that too.

What you use here is that if $p(a)=0$, then $(x-a)|p$.